# Erro de codificação de texto html na MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou tendo problema ao enviar textos acentuados ao banco de dados como palavras com **Ç Ã** etc.

Digamos que eu envie um texto assim **Isso e uma ação de postagem para você**

O que acontece e que só envia ata **Isso e uma a** o resto do texto não esta sendo enviado esta dando erro de codificar os textos. Como posso corrigir isso

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titulo_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `noticia` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  `hora` time NOT NULL,,
  `avatar` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `autor` char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tituloUnico` (`titulo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `urlUnica` (`titulo_url`),
  KEY `colunasIndexadas` (`id`,`titulo_url`,`autor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Não sei o motivo de estar dando esse erro no formulário de envio.

Comment: Qual é o charset que estás a usar na comunicação coma BD?

Comment: Estas a tentar guardar texto HTML como `<p>Isso e uma ação de postagem para você</p>` na BD?

Comment: Qual a linguagem que estás a usar?

Comment: utf8 acho que o problema deve estar no caso no e que não configurei o formato do arquivo ta em UTF8 deveria converter ele pra utf8 sem bom ?

Comment: Não sei, depende. Estas a ler um arquivo e a colocá-lo na BD? Ou é um formulário WEB?

Comment: Tente usar a codificação utf8_general_ci no banco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema está no `collate` e `Charset`.

Se o charset for `Latin1`, use o collate  `latin1_swedish_ci`

Se o charset for `UTF8`, use o collate `utf8_general_ci`

Você pode alterar usando os comandos:

```
ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` CHARSET = Latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;
```

ou

```
ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

Assim, a acentuação será enviada e interpretada corretamente pelo seu banco de dados.